# Proof that for m>n+1 inequalities with no feasible solution there are n+1 out of them with no feasible solution

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

I got the following question in Linear Programming class:

Let $a_1,...,a_m\in \Bbb R^n$ such that $m>n+1$. Assume that for the set of $m$ inequalities $a^t_ix ≤ b_i$ there is no feasible solution. Prove that there are $n+1$ inequalities out of the $m$ which are not feasible.

I tried to think of it in terms of the intersection of half-spaces in $\Bbb R^n$, which in this case is empty. But this didn't get me to something.

Comment: Maybe the Farkas lemma?

Comment: This is a direct consequence of Helly's theorem.

Comment: @SeanRoberson, I think the Farkas lemma is a good direction. I'm not sure how to derive this from it, though. According to the lemma, there is a vector $y \in \Bbb R^n$ such that $a_i^t y \ge 0 \quad \forall i=1,...,m$ and $by < 0$. Do you have an idea how to continue from here?